# How to make a MongoDB collection have an index that requires uniqueness with case insensitivity?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating a user schema and want case insensitivity on usernames. No two usernames should be similiar, even when considering capital letters.

I have added collation to the property with a locale of 'en' and a strength of 2. After this did not work, I directly entered MongoDB Compass and added the collation index with these values, which still did not work. The attempted code is as follows:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, collation: { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } },
        email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, collation: { locale: 'en', strength: 2 }, lowercase: true }
    }
);
```

I was expecting for a request to create a username named 'fred' to be denied when 'Fred' already existed in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the indexes explicitly:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true }
  }
);

UserSchema.index({ username: 1 }, { unique: true, collation: { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } });
UserSchema.index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true, collation: { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } });

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Be sure to delete the indexes that already exist in your database first.

Comment: This worked. It is worth noting for anyone looking here for a solution that it took a few minutes to create the index. If I immediately made a second document, it allowed duplicates. After a few minutes of waiting after making just one document, the index finally showed on MongoDb and it worked great.

Comment: That's good to hear. You can do `await User.syncIndexes();` to wait for the indexes to build. However this will also drop any indexes that aren't specified on the mongoose schema, so it's not appropriate if you do any index management separate from mongoose.